# Why Calling method through pure-virtual base class causing Seg Fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, abstract-class

I have an interface defined by four abstract base class definitions..  In the implementaiton that I have now I get a segmentation fault while calling a concrete class method via the abstract class pointer.

Calling the concrete class method directly works fine.

```
    #include <iostream> 
    
    enum Result_t 
    { 
        SUCCESS            
    };
    
    class DataCallback {
        public:
        virtual Result_t Callback(int32_t data) = 0;
        virtual ~DataCallback(){}
    };
    
    class DataCallback_Actual {
        public:
            Result_t Callback(int32_t data)
            {
                std::cout << m_name << ": int data update: " << data << std::endl;
                return SUCCESS;
            }
    
            DataCallback_Actual(const std::string & name):
            m_name(name) 
            {
                std::cout << "constructor DataCallback_Actual::DataCallback_Actual(" << m_name << ") @ 0x" << std::hex << this << std::endl;
            }
    
        private:
            std::string m_name;
    };
    
    int main(int argv, char **argc)
    {
        // Create a pointer to the concrete class
        DataCallback_Actual * pDataCallbackTwo_A = new DataCallback_Actual(std::string("Object-Two-Int"));
DataCallback_Actual(std::string("Object-Two-Int")));
    
        DataCallback * pDataCallbackTwo = (DataCallback *) pDataCallbackTwo_A;
    
        //
        // TODO: Why does the first call work but I get a segfault 
        //       when calling through the abstract pointer...
        //
        pDataCallbackTwo_A->Callback(10);
        pDataCallbackTwo->Callback(12);
    }
```

When I execute the sample program the Callback() method works fine when using the _A pointer but I get a segmentation fault when calling through the base class pointer...   The pointers are the same value.

A gdb sequence looks like..

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argv=21845, argc=0x7fffffffe1c0) at abstractFail.cpp:34
34  {
(gdb) n
36      DataCallback_Actual * pDataCallbackTwo_A = new DataCallback_Actual(std::string("Object-Two-Int"));
(gdb) n
constructor DataCallback_Actual::DataCallback_Actual(Object-Two-Int) @ 0x0x55555556aeb0
40      DataCallback * pDataCallbackTwo = (DataCallback *) pDataCallbackTwo_A;
(gdb) n
47      pDataCallbackTwo_A->Callback(10);
(gdb) p pDataCallbackTwo_A
$1 = (DataCallback_Actual *) 0x55555556aeb0
(gdb) p pDataCallbackTwo
$2 = (DataCallback *) 0x55555556aeb0
(gdb) n
Object-Two-Int: int data update: a
48      pDataCallbackTwo->Callback(12);
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555553f8 in main (argv=1, argc=0x7fffffffe308) at abstractFail.cpp:48
48      pDataCallbackTwo->Callback(12);
(gdb)
```

I use the same pattern with another abstract/concrete class pair and it works fine.  I don't like the fact that the two patterns are the same but one seg-faults and one does not.

Comment: `DataCallback` is not a base class of `DataCallback_Actual`.

Comment: `DataCallback *pDataCallbackTwo = (DataCallback *)pDataCallbackTwo_A;` whenever you have to `reinterpret_cast` check what you are really doing. Without the cast: `cannot convert 'DataCallback_Actual*' to 'DataCallback*' in initialization`

Comment: Lordy I'm a moron....

Comment: Suggestion: Get in the habit of using the `override` and `final` [specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) when declaring member functions of derived classes that are supposed to override virtual functions from a base class, because then the compiler will yell at you if, as in this case, you write a function that isn't actually overriding anything.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the culprit:

```cpp
DataCallback *pDataCallbackTwo = (DataCallback *)pDataCallbackTwo_A
```

You `reinterpret_cast` `pDataCallbackTwo_A` into something that it is not and access it as-if it were, which causes undefined behavior.

Make `DataCallback_Actual` a type of `DataCallback` by inheriting from `DataCallback`:

```cpp
class DataCallback_Actual : public DataCallback {
```

and then you don't even need the cast:

```cpp
DataCallback *pDataCallbackTwo = pDataCallbackTwo_A;
```

Comment: General rule of thumb: If you have to cast a function to make it fit a function pointer you've already lost. Change the function to match the pointer or change the pointer to match the function depending on which of the two you are allowed to change. Usually you're supplying a function to a pre-existing API and you're stuck supplying a function that matches the API.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, I agree and made a similar remark to OP under the question.

Comment: I see that now. It's the General-er rule of thumb: if you have to cast anything to fit a pointer stop and check twice.

Comment: Using the c-style cast allowed my code to compile..  I sure wish I had not lied to the compiler (with the cast) then never would have exposed my poor practice to everyone... 'sigh'

Comment: @DMLowe :-) The c-style cast here becomes a `reinterpret_cast<DataCallback*>` which is kind of the most brutal cast. It's sometimes necessary but very rarely and as user4581301 mentioned, when casting a pointer like that, it's usually a mistake. `dynamic_cast`s or `static_cast`s are preferred for pointers.